# Why was Louis Litt richer than all his bosses, given his lower salary and desperation to be made senior partner?

Tags: plot-explanation, suits

In Suits Season 6 episode 1, Louis Litt had his finest moment. Jessica, Harvey and Louis revealed their net-worth to each other. Everyone thought Louis was the poorest.  Jessica even thought Louis will be vulnerable and will be made to feel small. When Louis revealed his networth, all of them gasped. Harvey asked "Who are you? Are you a King?" Jessica was reduced to the point that she had to defend herself by replying "We are not exactly poor".

All of us wish we could do that to our bosses.

Why was Louis so rich when his salary throughout his career was lower than his bosses? Why so rich, yet so desperate to be made senior partner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why was Louis so rich when his salary throughout his career was lower than his bosses?**

Good Investments, Great Savings and Low maintenance.

Good Investments & Great Savings - knowing Louis, this has to be it.

Low Maintenance - For one I'm sure he does not splurge on 1000 dollar haircuts and impeccable suits like Harvey and doesn't need a designer wardrobe like Jessica.

And another fact - as a partner you have to invest some amount into the company funds (this is stated in season 1/2 cant recall during the Hardman issue)

**Why so rich, yet so desperate to be made senior partner?**

And money position & respect and are completely different things to want.
Louis may have all the money in the world but all that man ever wanted was to be treated like equals ever since S1. And being a member of the company and a senior partner are seas apart. The respect that comes with the position is what he always wanted and felt he deserved.

**Money cannot put his name up on the wall with Pearson & Spectar.**